# Why is sanic spawning multiple threads when a single worker is launched?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, sanic

I am launching a sanic app with a single worker in a docker container

```
root@2f69a2e79d16:/app# ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 10:22 ?        00:00:00 python -m sanic server.app --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000 --worker=1
root        12     0  0 10:23 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
root       336    12  0 10:24 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -ef
root@2f69a2e79d16:/app# 
root@2f69a2e79d16:/app# pstree -p 1
python(1)─┬─{python}(8)
          ├─{python}(9)
          ├─{python}(10)
          └─{python}(11)
```

Why is sanic launching multiple threads for a single worker ?

For one of our applications which uses sanic, I was seeing sanic launching around 21 threads ?

If sanic is lanuching threads for other management tasks, what is the count for the number of threads ? Are all the end requests served on a single thread ?

P.S: I don't see the code related to threads [here](https://github.com/huge-success/sanic/blob/0c4a9b1dce3d1af828e595dcdbd75199ef4d9eb2/sanic/server.py)

Comment: Sanic doesn't use threads. Send me a message on the community forums and I'll look more closely if you'd like. I'm curious to know how you are running it.

Comment: @TheBrewmaster The application is inside a docker container.I think you can reproduce this even with the getting started example.On my linux machine I just ran [this](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/getting_started.html#run-the-server) example.Found the pid using ps and pstree -p <pid> shows me below output.
`
    pstree -p 21192
    python(21192)─┬─{python}(21194)
                  ├─{python}(21195)
                  ├─{python}(21196)
                  └─{python}(21197)
`